# Subset permutation of one column based on the category of another column in pandas

Tags: pandas, subset, permutation

Here is one simplified case:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3], 'col2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'A', 'C', 'B', 'red', 'blue', 'greed']})
```

I want to do subset permutation on col2 with reference to col1. For example, only permute 'a', 'b', 'c' in col2 for they belong to category 1 in col1. And permute 'A', 'C', 'B' in category 2, then those colors in category 3. The output looks like below:

```
col1    col2
0   1   b
1   1   c
2   1   a
3   2   A
4   2   B
5   2   C
6   3   blue
7   3   red
8   3   green
```

For there are thousands of categories in col1, I'm thinking if there is a simple way instead of doing it in a loop one by one. Thank you.

Comment: what is the end use of this? do you need the col1 to be sorted like the original data?

Comment: Col2 is actually y variable. I want build y scrambling models for each group in  col1. The order of col1 doesn't have to be the same as the original.

Comment: so if you don't mind the order of col1 and just want a different order of appearance of values in col2 as long as they are associated to the same value of col1, maybe try `df.sample(frac=1)`

Comment: Random sampling won't change the label. For instance, the first item 0 in group 1 (col1) has a value of b in col2. What I wanted to do is change b to any values (a, b, c) in group 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df['col2'] = df.groupby('col1', as_index=False).col2.transform(np.random.permutation)
df
```

**Output**

```
    col1    col2
0   1       c
1   1       b
2   1       a
3   2       B
4   2       A
5   2       C
6   3      red
7   3      greed
8   3      blue
```

Comment: Thanks. That's what I'm looking for.